# Show code only on WooCommerce Pages

Tags: posts, woocommerce-offtopic, pages, conditional-content

Does anyone know how to put code into your theme that will only shop up on WooCommerce pages? I want to add a cart link but don't need it to shop up on the rest of the site. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you need no do is override WooCommerce templates. You can do this in your theme/child-theme directory. More detailed documentation can be found here --> https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

If you need further assistance please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put your code in the `is_woocommerce()` conditional tag.

> Returns true if on a page which uses WooCommerce templates (cart and
>   checkout are standard pages with shortcodes and thus are not
>   included).

For example:

```
if ( is_woocommerce() ) {
    enter code here
}
```

Read more information about WooCommerce Conditional tags at https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/